# Converting date element in a structured array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have parsed a data file which has the *second* element in `julian` date format.

```
array([(1957,  1, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999),
   (1957, 13, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999)],
  dtype=[('year', '<i4'), ('julian_date', '<i4'), ('1', '<i4'), ('2', '<i4'), ('3', '<i4'), ('4', '<i4'), ('5', '<i4'), ('6', '<i4'), ('7', '<i4'), ('8', '<i4'), ('9', '<i4'), ('10', '<i4'), ('11', '<i4'), ('12', '<i4')])
```

I would like to convert the `julian` *date to month* only in order to visualize my data.

I know how to perform simple manipulatations with the `julian_date` element such as:

```
galveston['julian_date'] - 1
array([  0,  12,  24, ..., 336, 348, 360], dtype=int32)
```

and I know that I can use the `datetime` function for this conversion:

```
datetime.date(1956, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(121 - 1)
```

which returns `datetime.date(1956, 4, 30)` where 4 is the month number,

However, I have no idea how to apply this to my data. I am new to `python` and programing in general, and I will appreciate any help.

Ok. I think I am getting close with the `.month` method. When I manually enter `year` and `julian_date`:

`x = datetime.date(1957, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(1 - 1)
galveston['julian_date'] = x.month`

It changes the element to corresponding month:

`array([(1957, 1, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999),(1957, 1, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999)],dtype=[('year', '<i4'), ('julian_date', '<i4'), ('1', '<i4'), ('2', '<i4'), ('3', '<i4'), ('4', '<i4'), ('5', '<i4'), ('6', '<i4'), ('7', '<i4'), ('8', '<i4'), ('9', '<i4'), ('10', '<i4'), ('11', '<i4'), ('12', '<i4')])`

However, they all receive the same month value, which is not what I need to do. When I tried to modify the function like this(this might be completely wrong btw):

`x = datetime.date('year', 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta('julian_date' - 1)
galveston['julian_date'] = x.month` I got an error.

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qWxW.png)

Comment: its not very clear for me, what you want to do, could you show the initial dataframe? and write what column you want to transform?

Comment: The `.month` method on a `datetime.date` object will return the corresponding month number only. Or you can use `%b` or `%B` to your choosing using the `.strftime` method on a `datetime` object to return the month name. If this helps, I'll post an answer - if not let me know.

Comment: Hello Frenchy, the original data type is list. Here are the first two lines from it: `['767A Galv 1957 001J  9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999\n',
 '767A Galv 1957 013J  9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999\n']` . I have parsed it to remove anything I don't need,                                       and also changed it to an array using `np.genfromtxt`. I am trying to plot time series, and need to change it and make it look like this : `array([('1957-01-01', 9999), ('1957-01-013', 9999)` - 1st and 2nd lines from the original list. Thank you

Comment: Hello Adam, Thank you, it does help because I wasn't aware about  `.month` method. I will try to use it.  I am not sure yet as to how to apply it to an entire array, but I will try to figure it out. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer to my own question. I used pandas library to convert the day of the year number to `datetime64` and from there I used `.month` method as was suggested by [Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10115683/adam).

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd

# Create object x of datetime64 type
# Here I use galveston data array and to_datetime function
x = pd.to_datetime(galveston['year'] * 1000 + galveston['julian_date'], format='%Y%j')

# Here is the look at 20 dates from the array
x[20:40]
DatetimeIndex(['1957-08-29', '1957-09-10', '1957-09-22', '1957-10-04',
           '1957-10-16', '1957-10-28', '1957-11-09', '1957-11-21',
           '1957-12-03', '1957-12-15', '1957-12-27', '1958-01-01',
           '1958-01-13', '1958-01-25', '1958-02-06', '1958-02-18',
           '1958-03-02', '1958-03-14', '1958-03-26', '1958-04-07'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

# Get the month and put it back into galveston array
galveston['month'] = x.month

#The final result where the second element is the month
galveston[20:40]
array([(1957,  8, 1253, 1314, 1248, 1253, 1277, 1269, 1270, 1272, 1271, 1219, 1222, 1261),
   (1957,  9, 1284, 1284, 1277, 1258, 1292, 1349, 1309, 1428, 1439, 1261, 1271, 1344),
   (1957,  9, 1345, 1301, 1363, 1433, 1352, 1206, 1221, 1281, 1273, 1303, 1317, 1268),
   (1957, 10, 1172, 1177, 1307, 1319, 1280, 1215, 1166, 1208, 1281, 1384, 1510, 1598),
   (1957, 10, 1454, 1309, 1296, 1341, 1369, 1503, 1584, 1414, 1194, 1193, 1095, 1001),
   (1957, 10, 1060, 1111, 1159, 1141, 1184, 1193, 1140, 1205, 1287, 1278, 1348, 1148),
   (1957, 11, 1184, 1441, 1580, 1584, 1507, 1313, 1350, 1373, 1371, 1272, 1109, 1193),
   (1957, 11, 1284, 1365, 1199, 1064,  951, 1057, 1189, 1165, 1028,  666,  835,  996),
   (1957, 12, 1000,  929, 1116, 1253, 1084,  728,  625,  856,  617,  828, 1035, 1055),
   (1957, 12, 1011, 1069, 1090, 1105, 1142,  957,  949, 1127, 1180, 1089, 1090, 1083),
   (1957, 12, 1180, 1091, 1092, 1171, 1118, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999),
   (1958,  1,  965, 1104, 1161, 1298, 1517, 1443, 1082,  879, 1011,  974, 1013, 1233),
   (1958,  1,  929,  823,  776,  675,  804,  873, 1159, 1158,  667,  784, 1218,  972),
   (1958,  1,  824,  888,  833,  914,  994,  964,  916,  641,  645,  780,  940,  986),
   (1958,  2,  928,  702,  833, 1071, 1117, 1020,  937,  910, 1079,  741,  757, 1082),
   (1958,  2, 1111, 1106, 1161, 1180, 1214, 1145,  964, 1008, 1125,  979,  841,  958),
   (1958,  3, 1061, 1016, 1112, 1237, 1146, 1142, 1119, 1011, 1070, 1169, 1191,  918),
   (1958,  3,  847,  924,  963, 1010,  937,  947,  907,  878,  950, 1050,  926,  936),
   (1958,  3,  954,  948, 1002, 1128, 1035,  995, 1111, 1164, 1140, 1147, 1231, 1127),
   (1958,  4,  980, 1221, 1315, 1033,  916, 1045, 1147, 1129,  942,  857,  946,  974)],
  dtype=[('year', '<i4'), ('month', '<i4'), ('1', '<i4'), ('2', '<i4'), ('3', '<i4'), ('4', '<i4'), ('5', '<i4'), ('6', '<i4'), ('7', '<i4'), ('8', '<i4'), ('9', '<i4'), ('10', '<i4'), ('11', '<i4'), ('12', '<i4')])
```